# How to hide an element if a button was not clicked for a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a simple Coin Flip project to hone my JS skills.

I have a `<div id="winMessage">` and I want it to be hidden if I don't click the button for a few seconds. How can I achieve something like this?

I have tried using `style.visibility` and `sleep()` to hide/show it between lines but it seems so inefficient and causes lots of problems on other parts.

```js
let heads = 0, tails = 0;

let coinFlip = () => {
    let flip = () => {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    }

    let result = flip();

    if (result === 1){
        heads++;
        document.getElementById("winMessage").innerHTML = "Heads!"
    }

    else if (result === 2) {
        tails++;
        document.getElementById("winMessage").innerHTML = "Tails!"
    }

    document.getElementById("heads").innerText = heads;
    document.getElementById("tails").innerHTML = tails;
}
```

````html
<head>

    <title>Coin Flipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="bg-dark text-warning" style="margin: auto;">
    <header>
        <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
    </header>

    <form>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="coinFlip()" style="width: 100%;">Flip It!</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="winMessage" style="float: center; text-align: center; font-size: 100px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></div>

    <div style="float: center; text-align: center;">
        <div>Heads Count: <div id="heads" style=></div></div>
        <div>Tails Count: <div id="tails"></div></div>
    </div>

</body>
```
````

Comment: Not an answer but a pointer in the right direction: Create a function (which hides the element) and use `setTimeout(functionname, 3000)`  where 3000 is the delay in ms.  Careful though, those are the first steps into async-territory and there's a minor obstacle for all newcomers to grasp the complexities with functions that will run at some point in the future. But its no biggie, just embrace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout):

- `const hide = setTimeout()` in main scope, with your delay as a second argument
- `clearTimeout(hide)` on the button click
- `element.style.display = "none"` to hide the element
- optionally, as you use Bootstrap, I guess you can use [jQuery `.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide) instead

```js
let heads = 0, tails = 0;

let coinFlip = () => {
    clearTimeout(hide);
    let flip = () => {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    }

    let result = flip();

    if (result === 1){
        heads++;
        document.getElementById("winMessage").innerHTML = "Heads!"
    }

    else if (result === 2) {
        tails++;
        document.getElementById("winMessage").innerHTML = "Tails!"
    }

    document.getElementById("heads").innerText = heads;
    document.getElementById("tails").innerHTML = tails;
}


const hide = setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('winMessage').style.display = 'none'
}, 3000)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
    <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
</header>

<form>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="coinFlip()" style="width: 100%;">Flip It!</button>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="winMessage" style="float: center; text-align: center; font-size: 100px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Hides after 3000ms</div>

<div style="float: center; text-align: center;">
    <div>Heads Count: <div id="heads" style=></div></div>
    <div>Tails Count: <div id="tails"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it initially shows the message "Hides after..." then does nothing on the succeeding messages. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, it is just for example purposes - I gave you the tools, business logic is for you to be implemented :). Toggle those two functions to your needs.

Comment: Oh, for a moment I thought you misunderstood my question. Thank you for the answer, I'll try it now!

Comment: Have fun mate, I'm sure you'll get there :).

Answer (score 1):

You should start a timer at the start of your program. Every time the button is pressed then the timer should be erased and a new timer should start. Here is an example using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).

```js
var time = 5000;
var timeoutID = setTimeout(hideElement, time);

document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", delay);

function delay() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  timeoutID = setTimeout(hideElement, time);
}

function hideElement() {
  document.querySelector("#hide").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="hide">Hiding</div>
<button id="button">Delay</button>
```

This is how it would look like on your question:

```js
let heads = 0,
  tails = 0;

const time = 5000;
let timeoutID = setTimeout(hideMessage, time);

let coinFlip = () => {
  let flip = () => {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
  }

  let result = flip();

  if (result === 1) {
    heads++;
    document.getElementById("winMessage").innerHTML = "Heads!"
  } else if (result === 2) {
    tails++;
    document.getElementById("winMessage").innerHTML = "Tails!"
  }

  document.getElementById("heads").innerText = heads;
  document.getElementById("tails").innerHTML = tails;
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  timeoutID = setTimeout(hideMessage, time);
  // If you do not want it to reappear, remove this line
  document.querySelector("#winMessage").style.display = null;
};

function hideMessage() {
  document.querySelector("#winMessage").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<head>

  <title>Coin Flipper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="bg-dark text-warning" style="margin: auto;">
  <header>
    <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
  </header>

  <form>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="coinFlip()" style="width: 100%;">Flip It!</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div id="winMessage" style="float: center; text-align: center; font-size: 100px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></div>

  <div style="float: center; text-align: center;">
    <div>Heads Count:
      <div id="heads" style=></div>
    </div>
    <div>Tails Count:
      <div id="tails"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the simple way use css. With css animation.

```css
@keyframes showHide {
   0% { opacity: 0; }
   10% { opacity: 0.2 }
   20% { opacity: 0.35 }
   50% { opacity: 1 }
   60% { opacity: 0.75 }
   100 % { opacity: 0; }
 }
 
#winMessage {
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation-name: showHide;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate; 
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="winMessage" style="float: center; text-align: center; font-size: 100px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```js
setTimeout(() => {  
    document.getElementById("winMessage").style.display = 'none'; 
}, 3000); // 3 seconds
```

```html
<div id="winMessage">winMessage</div>
```